# JS + Cypress : unable to get the output from a function

Tags: javascript, cypress

I recently started playing with JS and looking into Cypress to write some simple test automation.

my code writes the following:

```
    Cypress.Commands.add("setup", (email, password) => {
    getAccessToken(email, password).then(console.log)
   
  })

  function getAccessToken (email, password) {
    cy.request('POST', 'testurl',{       
        "email": email,
       "password": password
       }).then((response) => {
           return response.body.access_token
       })
  }
```

console.log prints access_token just fine if I place it within getAccessToken at where the return statement is.. but the console.log prints unidentified if I call it in the command setup even after using .then, (my goal is to get the access_token and use it as an input for another function within "setup")

Comment: I'd strongly recommend reading through https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases

Comment: Please see blog [Why cy.log Prints Nothing](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/why-cy-log-prints-nothing/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return` only returns the `response.body.access_token` in the Cypress chain. If you added a `.then()` after the one in your function, you would have correctly yielded the value.

Instead, you can return the entire `cy.request()` chain in your function, and see the response.

```js
  function getAccessToken (email, password) {
    return cy.request('POST', 'testurl',{       
        "email": email,
       "password": password
       }).then((response) => {
           return response.body.access_token
       })
  }
```

Tested with this code:

```js
    const getTest = () => {
      return cy.request('http://www.google.com').then((res) => {
        return res.body;
      });
    };

    getTest().then(console.log);
```